# How to iterate JSON array in Ballerina

Tags: json, ballerina

```
json data = {"vals": ["a", "b", "c"]};
```

How to iterate above JSON and get a,b,c?

Answer (score 0):

```
public function main() returns error? {
    json data = {"vals": ["a", "b", "c"]};

    json vals = check data.vals;
    json[] arr = check vals.ensureType();

    //// or just
    // json[] arr = check data.vals.ensureType(); 
    
    foreach json item in arr {
        
    }
}
```

We need to narrow the type down to an iterable type after accessing the field as shown above.

Answer (score 0):

You can use the following approach if you are unsure of the JSON field name in advance.

```
public function main() {
    json data = {"vals": ["a", "b", "c"]};
    if data !is map<json> {
        return;
    }
    foreach [string, json] [fieldName, value] in data.entries() {
        if value is json[] {
            io:println("Field Name : ", fieldName);
            io:print("Array Values : ");
            iterateJsonArray(value);
        }
    }
}

function iterateJsonArray(json[] arr) {
    foreach json member in arr {
        io:print(member, " ");
    }
}
```